# Is my Nvidia dead?

Tags: debian, drivers, nvidia, optimus

I am on Debian Jessie. I just wanted to install Nvidia drivers. But I found `nvidia-detect` does not detect my dedicated chip. Although it is listed in `lshw`.

**`lshw -c video`** before any installation

```
# lshw -c video
  *-display               
       description: 3D controller
       product: GK107M [GeForce GT 750M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:51 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:49 memory:f7400000-f77fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

**`lshw -c video`** after installation and uninstallation of Nvidia drivers and blacklisting nouveau -> upon request

**`$ lspci | grep VGA`**

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
```

**`$ lspci | grep NVIDIA`**

```
$ lspci | grep NVIDIA
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 750M] (rev a1)
```

**`$ lspci -vnnn | egrep 'VGA|NVIDIA'`**

```
$ lspci -vnnn | egrep 'VGA|NVIDIA'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0416] (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 750M] [10de:0fe4] (rev a1)
```

Notice, the Nvidia is not listed under VGA.

So, the HW is detected.

But **I installed Nvidia drivers** according to this http://linuxconfig.org/nvidia-geforce-driver-installation-on-debian-jessie-linux-8-64bit and rebooted (into console) and ran `nvidia-detect`

**AND IT SAYS**

**`nvidia-detect`**

```
# nvidia-detect
No NVIDIA GPU detected.
```

I am unable to `startx`, it ended up with an error. In the log I saw *No screens detected* or similar.

So, what is wrong? Is the dedicated chip dead?

Comment: what does `lspci | grep VGA` show?

Comment: you have one of those switching dual GPU laptops.  iirc you need to install something called bumblebee to get it to switch modes.  you also need the proprietary driver...it's a recent GPU so the latest driver package (i.e. not the legacy driver package) should work.  on debian sid, that would be `nvidia-driver`.  dunno about other distros.

Comment: on further reading about it, it seems that bumblee is no longer needed.  recentish (>=2014) `nvidia-settings` can detect and switch, so you need `nvidia-settings` as well as `nvidia-driver`

Comment: https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Supported-drivers

Comment: btw, "because i prefer open source" is a reason to use nouveau driver.  "because i prefer stability" is a reason to use nvidia driver.  The open source driver is still, unfortunately, many years behind the proprietary nvidia driver in terms of features, hardware support, and stability.

Comment: The same question as http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/194463/79743

Comment: Now days optimus NVIDIA cards are little bit difficult to handle then they were before, specially with new UEFI hardware. Though its late, please have a look there if you want to configure your card with non-free nvidia driver, I'hv written one article about it. http://fixmynix.com/install-and-configure-nvidia-optimus-with-bumblebee-in-debian/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason you're having problems is that your video card requires the proprietary nvidia 352 driver and the only driver available in the jessie, jessie-backports, and sid repositores is the version 340 driver.  You should check on the [Nvidia website drivers page](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx) to verify the version your card requires.

The proprietary version 352 driver is currently available only in the Debian `experimental` repository.  I've pulled it down and built the package on jessie.  It's a noodle soup of dependency problems and will be a major task to install it in jessie (at least with my knowledge of the situation).

That leaves two options: install the free drivers, or let the nvidia installer loose on your system.  Both Debian and Arch (haven't checked others) and I strongly recommend ***against*** installing the proprietary drivers outside of the respective package management system

If this was my system, I would install the free drivers and wait for the packages in experimental to make it to sid or jessie-backports before trying again.

This from the Official Debian Wiki [NvidiaGraphicsDrivers](https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers)  page:

> As of jessie, the need for the proprietary drivers is pretty much over - nouveau now works quite well and works with dual-headed displays by simple and easy configuring from within your desktop. The proprietary drivers don't provide normal logging and can be a hidden source of problems. If you are doing a distribution upgrade - you should at the very least remove all the nvidia packages from wheezy - get your desktop working with nouveau - then reinstall the nvidia packages if there is a pressing reason.

I would follow the directions on the [Official Debian Wiki Bumblebee page](https://wiki.debian.org/Bumblebee/) and make sure to install the `bumblebee` package ***not*** `bumblebee-nvidia`.